# How is the precession rate of planets calculated? For which planets do we know the precession rates?

Tags: astronomy, planets, solar-system, celestial-mechanics, precession

From what I've read, precession rates of Earth, Mars and Moon are known. Why is that? 
And how is it calculated?

Comment: Astronomy SE would be a better site for this question. As it is, this question does not ask about a specific physics concept.

Comment: I think a little research on the part of the OP might also be useful, v.g. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node115.html

Comment: @Yashas: Astronomy and astrophysics questions are perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: Calculated, or measured?

Comment: Given that there are already four close votes on this question, I'm not going to waste my time and write an answer. This is a very answerable question and is quite on-topic. I'll wait until the question is closed and reopened. To the questioner: There are two very different kinds of precession: axial precession, in which a planet's rotation axis precesses with respect to inertial, and perihelion precession, in which a planet's perihelion precesses with respect to inertial. Which do you mean? (I can answer both questions.)